# Plotting more lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have input file that stores data in this format:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2
```

That is one row and it represents two points for a line. Now, I have many such rows
and for each row I need to draw a line. Is there some efficient method to do this?
Do I have to go through each line separately with a for loop? What command do I use
to draw line?

Thank you

Comment: I am not stuck, I ask about efficient ways to do it. Is it OK if I use for loop and draw each line separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, you might need to change the `%f %f %f %f` format:

```
fid = fopen('yourfile', 'r');

C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f');

fclose(fid);

figure(100)
plot(C{:, 1}, C{:, 2}, C{:, 3}, C{:, 4}); % column based lines

figure(200)
plot([C{1} C{3}]', [C{2}, C{4}]'); % row based lines
```

;

Comment: But what if I have 1000 lines?

Comment: textscan will read them all, if you want the first 1000 to be read then use `C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 1000`, check out the documentation

Comment: For drawing this sort of line you may find `line` is a better function that `plot`. Also, don't forget to use `hold all` or simmilar to allow plotting multiple things on the same figure.

Comment: @Alan if you only need to draw 2 lines then you do not need `hold on/off`, plot(x1, y1, x2, y1) will do the same thing,

Comment: @Nick, I tested your answer, and it gave an incorrect plot. Admittedly `hold on/off` is unnecessary if you plot the lines with a single call to `line`/`plot`, such as providing the coordinates as matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking into this further I find the plotting method in the other answer doesn't work quite as expected.

When tested with the following input file:

```
0 1 3 2
1 2 9 4
5 6 7 8
```

Judging by the question this should give a plot of three straight lines. Line 1 should start at coordinate x=0, y=1 and terminate at point x=3, y=2. Similarly for the rest.

When read with the code provided:

```
fid = fopen('yourfile', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f');
fclose(fid);
```

The resulting value of `C` is `C = {[0;1;5], [1;2;6], [3;9;7], [2;4;8]};`. This is all fine and good.

When plotted with `plot(C{:, 1}, C{:, 2}, C{:, 3}, C{:, 4});` This is the result:
[image: plot(C{:, 1}, C{:, 2}, C{:, 3}, C{:, 4});]

This is because plot will draw a line series for `X=C{:,1}; Y=C{:,2};`, both of which in this example are three points long, and another line for `X=C{:,3}; Y=C{:,4};`

In order to plot three separate lines, with the endpoints specified by `[x1 y1]`, `[x2 y2]`, you could use the following code:

```
plot([C{1} C{3}]', [C{2}, C{4}]');
```

`plot`, when provided with matrices as the X and Y parameters will plot a separate line for each column, so this results in:

[image: plot([C{1} C{3}]', [C{2}, C{4}]');]

Comment: as stated in the question, the file consisted of `x1 y1 x2 y2`, so I suppose 2 lines where requested as seen in your first plot.

Comment: @Nick "That is one row and it represents two points for a line. Now, I have **many such rows** and **for each row I need to draw a line**." (emphasis added)

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll adapt the answer, but I wonder whether the -1 was needed :)